# Querying for vendors and categories

Tags: php, sql

I'm looking for pointers on the best way to optimize my code below. The query is designed to pull for a vendor database in a separate SQL server table that I built a connection to in my wordpress site.

I've created three different queries based on the value that gets passed in a search field. Either it's a vendor name, category name, or finally a category id. I'm trying to optimize it so in the future when I need to update the columns that are being pulled I don't have to update multiple statements.

Any thoughts or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$searchInput='xyz';
if(isset($_GET['searchInput'])){
    $searchInput= $_GET['searchInput'];
 }
 $searchcat_id ='';
 if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){
    $searchcat_id= $_GET['category_id'];
 }
if (isset($_POST['searchInput'])) {
    $searchInput = sanitize_text_field($_POST['searchInput']);
}
$conn = get_sql_connect();
if ($conn === false) {
    $content = ['Error in connecting the SQL Server'];
} else {
    if($searchInput=='All Vendors'){
        $query = "select * from vendor";
    }else{
        $query = "select * from vendor where vendorName LIKE '".$searchInput."'";
    }
    $datatable_value = array();
    $stm = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
    $flag = 0;
    // When there is no categry name in search. We are only searching by Vendor name
    while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stm, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $flag = 1;
        $ven_query = "SELECT cat.category_name, ven.vendorID
                    FROM vendor AS ven
                    JOIN vendor_category AS vencat ON ven.vendorID = vencat.vendor_id 
                    JOIN category AS cat ON vencat.category_id  = cat.category_id 
                    WHERE ven.vendorName LIKE '%".str_replace("'","''",$rows['vendorName'])."%'";
        $ven_stm = sqlsrv_query($conn, $ven_query);
        while ($values = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ven_stm, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $rows['serviceCategory'] = $values['category_name'];
            $rows['Details'] = '<a href="'.get_home_url().'/vendor-information/?vendor='.$searchInput.'&category='.$values['category_name'].'&id='.$values['vendorID'].'">View</a>';
            $datatable_value[] = $rows;
        }
    }
    // We are seaching by category name and no Vendor.
    if($flag == 0 && $searchcat_id == ''){
        $cat_query = "SELECT
                        V.vendorID,
                        V.vendorName,
                        V.contact_name,
                        V.email,
                        V.phone,
                        V.supplierID,
                        C.category_name
                    FROM
                        vendor AS V
                    JOIN
                        vendor_category AS VC ON V.vendorID = VC.vendor_id
                    JOIN
                        category AS C ON VC.category_id = C.category_id
                    WHERE
                        C.category_name LIKE '%".str_replace("'","''",$searchInput)."%'";
        $cat_stm = sqlsrv_query($conn, $cat_query);
        if(!empty($cat_stm)){
            while ($value = sqlsrv_fetch_array($cat_stm, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $value['Details'] = '<a href="'.get_home_url().'/vendor-information/?vendor='.$value['vendorName'].'&category='.$searchInput.'&id='.$value['vendorID'].'">View</a>';
                $datatable_value[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $temp_query = "SELECT DISTINCT c4.category_id
                        FROM category c1
                        JOIN category c2 ON c1.category_id = c2.category_id OR c1.category_id = c2.parent_category_id
                        JOIN category c3 ON c2.category_id = c3.category_id OR c2.category_id = c3.parent_category_id
                        JOIN category c4 ON c3.category_id = c4.category_id OR c3.category_id = c4.parent_category_id
                        WHERE c1.category_id = ".$searchcat_id;
        $temp_stm = sqlsrv_query($conn, $temp_query);
        if(!empty($temp_stm)){
            while ($value_temp = sqlsrv_fetch_array($temp_stm, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                //echo $value_temp['category_id'].'----';                
                $cat_query = "SELECT
                                V.vendorID,
                                V.vendorName,
                                V.contact_name,
                                V.email,
                                V.phone,
                                V.supplierID,
                                C.category_name
                            FROM
                                vendor AS V
                            JOIN
                                vendor_category AS VC ON V.vendorID = VC.vendor_id
                            JOIN
                                category AS C ON VC.category_id = C.category_id
                            WHERE
                                C.category_id = ".$value_temp['category_id'];
                //echo $cat_query.'/n'; 
                $cat_stm = sqlsrv_query($conn, $cat_query);
                if(!empty($cat_stm)){
                    //echo 'here::::';
                    while ($value = sqlsrv_fetch_array($cat_stm, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        //print_r($value);
                        $value['Details'] = '<a href="'.get_home_url().'/vendor-information/?vendor='.$value['vendorName'].'&category='.$searchInput.'&id='.$value['vendorID'].'">View</a>';
                        $datatable_value[] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/287960/revisions#rev-body-ba2e07ee-22c4-48c3-8b57-6b946e8d44ba) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

## consistent defaults

```
$searchInput='xyz';
```

Prefer to initialize to the empty string,
for consistency with `$searchcat_id`.

[Repeating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
the key names seems tedious.
Can't we write something like
`$searchInput = $_GET['searchInput'] ?? '';` ?
Otherwise extract a helper function to that effect.

---

## document the Public API

The GET / POST cases seem to support
different sets of input parameters.

Document that.

At this point it's unclear to me why `category_id`
shall not appear in a POST. (Or in any event shall be ignored.)

---

## sql injection

```
    if ($searchInput == 'All Vendors') {
        $query = "select * from vendor";
    } else {
        $query = "select * from vendor where vendorName LIKE '".$searchInput."'";
    }
```

This is nice enough as written.

Rather than `$searchInput` we apparently should have
named it `$vendorName`.

A typical way to construct such a query string would be
to unconditionally assign that first one,
and then conditionally tack on the WHERE clause.

The bad part shows up in that WHERE condition. You are vulnerable to
[sql injection](https://xkcd.com/327),
due to interpolating an attacker-controlled string.
Prefer to use bind parameters, so quoting isn't even an issue.
Similarly for `$ven_query` and `$cat_query`.

---

## disjuncts

```
        $temp_query = "SELECT DISTINCT c4.category_id
                        FROM category c1
                        JOIN category c2 ON c1.category_id = c2.category_id OR c1.category_id = c2.parent_category_id
                        JOIN category c3 ON c2.category_id = c3.category_id OR c2.category_id = c3.parent_category_id
                        JOIN category c4 ON c3.category_id = c4.category_id OR c3.category_id = c4.parent_category_id
                        WHERE c1.category_id = ".$searchcat_id;
```

The use of OR makes me nervous.
If you do an EXPLAIN PLAN I wouldn't be surprised
to see that you've disabled all indexes
and are resorting to tablescan.

Often a `c1 OR c2` boils down to doing a pair
of queries, for `c1` and subsequently for `c2`.
You can issue each query yourself, and then you see separate timings,
or the backend can (slowly) do it for you, obscuring the timing details.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the points mentioned by J_H. [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/1575353) may be arguably the biggest concern, at least in terms of security. Check out [The Hitchhiker's Guide to SQL Injection prevention](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection) for tips on preventing it. Other aspects to be considered are below.

## Prefer using type-safe comparison operators

The check of `$conn` uses strict-type equality:

> ```
> if ($conn === false) {
> ```

However the comparisons of `$flag` and `searchcat_id` do not:

> ```
> if($flag == 0 && $searchcat_id == ''){
> ```

`$flag` is only ever assigned an integer (i.e. `0` or `1`) and `$searchcat_id` is only assigned string values. [It is a good habit to use strict equality operators](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/126585/244085) whenever possible.

## Spacing can be more consistent

The seventh line contains no spacing after the `if` keyword:

> ```
>  if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){
> ```

Whereas the tenth line has one space after the `if` keyword:

> ```
> if (isset($_POST['searchInput'])) {
> ```

The second approach is generally used more frequently in idiomatic PHP code. It also adheres the the [PSR-12 style guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) [Section 5](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#5-control-structures).

Also notice there is an extra space of indentation for lines five through nine:

> ```
> if(isset($_GET['searchInput'])){
>     $searchInput= $_GET['searchInput'];
>  }
>  $searchcat_id ='';
>  if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){
>     $searchcat_id= $_GET['category_id'];
>  }
> ```

Spacing around binary operators can also be more consistent. The third line has no space before the assignment operator and one space after it:

> ```
> $searchInput= $_GET['searchInput'];
> ```

While the eleventh line does have a space before and after the assignment operator:

> ```
> $content = ['Error in connecting the SQL Server'];
> ```

This adheres to PSR-12 section [6.2. Binary operators](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#62-binary-operators)

PSR-12 also has numerous other recommendations - including the following in section [2.2 Files](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#22-files):

> The closing `?>` tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP.